# Can I create a "copy" button using Javascript that replicates selecting with mouse and copying an image rendered on html webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-email, clipboard

**Background**

I built a web app in HTML/Javascript that renders an HTML email in the browser. The user copies the rendered email and pastes the contents into their email body in Gmail.

**The problem**

To copy the HTML, a user must drag his mouse over ALL of the rendered HTML (which is several screens long and tricky to do), and ctrl + v to copy. Here is a video showing the manual process https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/17109459?key=84ec2c8f480865cf013b51256f4e2492

I want to create a "copy to clipboard" button that allows the user to do this in one click.

**To replicate problem**

Add the following basic HTML email code to a webpage. One clicked, the button should copy the image and teal background box. If pasted into gmail (or Outlook), it should render the same image with tea background.

```js
function copyClipboard(){
  let copyText = $("#emailRender").html();
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
}
$(".copyHtmlMail").click(function(){
  copyClipboard();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="copyHtmlMail">Copy rendered html</button>

<!--container for email-->
<div id="emailRender">
<!--HTML email code-->
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#327478;text-align:center;">
    <table width="640" role="presentation" style="width:640px;border:0;border-spacing:0;margin:0px auto;">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <h1>Title</h1>
          <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/210284/header.png" width="640" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</div>
```

**Solutions tried**

I have tried using jQuery .html(), but this simply pastes the HTML inside the Gmail body, and not the rendered HTML.

Is there any way to do this with Javascript/jQuery?

Thank you

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. If copying to clipboard is the main problem, did you try to adapt any of the existing solutions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72595339/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-js